# name on card when it is a business card, submitting in DoDirectPayment PayPal

Tags: paypal

I am using DoDirectPayment to process credit cards through PayPal. It all works great when using personal credit cards. When using a business credit card with a business name on the card and not a first and last name, how do I process that?

DoDirectPayment only has FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME variables in the payer information, how do I submit a business name on card?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The name really doesn't get involved in the card verification.  Most business cards would have a company name and a regular person's name on it, but if all it has is a company name you could just git that into the first and last name fields however it'll fit.

For example, with my company, Angell EYE, I would use first name Angell and last name EYE.

Comment: Awesome! What about if the name is just one word? PayPal documentation says FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME fields are required. I can add the company name into the first name, what would I put into the LASTNAME? just add a random character?

Comment: Ok yes, just tested it. I just added "na" into the last name if there is only one word and it seems to work.